# Sending SOAP messages WCF client that include a username token and digital signature but are NOT encrypted

Tags: .net, soap, wcf-security, wcf-client

WCF does my head in. What I'm trying to do is create a WCF client that will send SOAP messages that contain a username token and are signed with a certificate, but are not encrypted. I've found many articles and blogs with code which almost does what I want, but not quite, and now I'm stumped. Can anyone give me a *simple* example of how to do this?

What I've done so far is:

- Use svcutil to generate a config file and WCF code from a wsdl and xsd
- Install certificates and load from the certificate store

I've tried many different things and had many different errors and would like a an example which is as simple as possible so I can a) have some chance of understanding it and b) figure out what I need to change to make the code work.

Answer (score -1):

Just a guess, but you could try [TransportCredentialOnly](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2006/07/31/890.aspx).  I had trouble last year trying to call a SOAP service with using a WCF client with basic authentication over http and couldn't get it to work.  I found a few articles on line but couldn't get any to work.

Comment: That is not an answer.  You basically said that you failed to get anything to works.