# WCF custom binding that will support HTTPS, a signed certificate and a signed username token

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding

I've tried asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026743/sending-soap-messages-wcf-client-that-include-a-username-token-and-digital-signat) about WCF but I've got no answers so I'm trying again with a more focused question.

Can anyone tell me how to create a custom binding for a WCF client that will:

- include a signed username token
- include a signed message
- be sent over HTTPS

UPDATE

Not sure if it makes a difference but I'm using .NET 4

ANOTHER UPDATE

If anyone has any specific examples that would be awesome

Comment: This isn't the answer but I'm come across a useful utility, the [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732009.aspx](configuration editor tool) which has a GUI and wizards for creating/editing WCF configurations

Answer (score 4):

I think i can give some pointers. You will have to use WIF to get this working.  The username token which you want to pass would be a SAML token that is signed. To generate the SAML token, there is a STS sample project that comes with WCF sample, you can use that sample project. Your code should look something like this:

```
            //This class will use the STS WCF sample to generate the signed SAML token
            var tm = new TokenManager();
            var samlToken = tm.GetSamlToken(Username);
            var cf2 = new ChannelFactory<IPingService>("WcfSamlOverMutualSsl");
            cf2.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = clientCert;

            cf2.ConfigureChannelFactory();

            cf2.Open();
            // this code will attach the SAML token to WCF service.
            var proxy2 = cf2.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(samlToken);
            response = proxy2.Ping();
```

Config should look something like this:

```
<customBinding>
        <binding name="SamlOverMutualSsl">
          <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default" authenticationMode="IssuedTokenOverTransport"
              requireDerivedKeys="true" securityHeaderLayout="Strict" includeTimestamp="false"
              keyEntropyMode="CombinedEntropy" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10">
            <issuedTokenParameters keyType="BearerKey" tokenType="">
              <additionalRequestParameters>
                <trust:SecondaryParameters xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
                  <trust:KeyType xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Bearer</trust:KeyType>
                </trust:SecondaryParameters>
              </additionalRequestParameters>
            </issuedTokenParameters>
            <localClientSettings cacheCookies="true" detectReplays="false"
                replayCacheSize="900000" maxClockSkew="00:05:00" maxCookieCachingTime="Infinite"
                replayWindow="00:05:00" sessionKeyRenewalInterval="10:00:00"
                sessionKeyRolloverInterval="00:05:00" reconnectTransportOnFailure="true"
                timestampValidityDuration="00:05:00" cookieRenewalThresholdPercentage="60" />
            <localServiceSettings detectReplays="false" issuedCookieLifetime="10:00:00"
                maxStatefulNegotiations="128" replayCacheSize="900000" maxClockSkew="00:05:00"
                negotiationTimeout="00:01:00" replayWindow="00:05:00" inactivityTimeout="00:02:00"
                sessionKeyRenewalInterval="15:00:00" sessionKeyRolloverInterval="00:05:00"
                reconnectTransportOnFailure="true" maxPendingSessions="128"
                maxCachedCookies="1000" timestampValidityDuration="00:05:00" />
            <secureConversationBootstrap />
          </security>
          <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
              messageVersion="Soap11" writeEncoding="utf-8">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
              maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
              bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
              keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
              realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
              useDefaultWebProxy="true" requireClientCertificate="true" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
```

Endpoint :

```
<endpoint address="https://localhost/Ping/saml"
          binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="SamlOverMutualSsl"
          contract="SharedContracts.IPingService" name="WcfSamlOverMutualSsl" />
```

Please add the reference to the Microsoft.IdentityModel from WIF.

Comment: Sorry I can't find the Microsoft.IdentityModel reference. What am I missing?

Comment: You will have to install the Microsoft Windows indentity foundataion (WIF) to get the reference

Comment: Could you point me to the specific example which you got this code from please? I've downloaded [these samples](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21459) but I can't find the relevant code

Comment: the code sample, i have pasted doesn't come from any sample. i have just given you the flow of the way your code should look like.

Comment: Fair enough. Unfortunately my knowledge of WCF is terrible so I'm struggling to turn this into working code